# Can't see the send button in HTML contact form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple HTML contact form, but when I upload the HTML page to the internet, the send and clear buttons are not showing up - they're invisible.
The funny thing is if I hover the mouse over where they are supposed to be, I can see that there is a button there.
Why could this be?

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post"> 
  <div>
    <label for="contactname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="contactname" class="textfield" id="contactname" value=""  />
    <span class="require"> *</span>
    <label for="contactsubject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="contactsubject" class="textfield" id="contactsubject" value=""/>
    <span class="require"> *</span>
    <label for="contactemail">Your E-mail</label> 
    <input type="text" name="contactemail" class="textfield" id="contactemail" value="" />
    <span class="require"> *</span>
    <label for="contactmessage">Your Message</label> 
    <textarea name="contactmessage" id="contactmessage" class="textarea" cols="8" rows="12"></textarea>
    <span class="require"> *</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `/` end slash to both send & clear

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

and

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
```

or you can also do like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"></input>
<input type="reset" value="Clear"></input>
```

`<input>` is starting tag
`</input>` is ending tag

UPDATE 1: answer for how to use image for submit button

> change input type to "image"

```
<input type="image" value="submit" src="submit1.jpg" alt="submit Button" onMouseOver="this.src='submit1.jpg'">
```

Comment: @Imray: it is tag closing symbol

Comment: Thanks! The second one seems more familiar but I'm still new and missed it.  Can I ask you one more question? What if I want to use my own Send button (an image I have)- What would I add to the code?

Comment: <input type="image" value="submit" src="submit1.jpg" alt="submit Button">

Comment: Thank you!! You are brilliant! You've really helped me learn.